# Not able to get correct Nano Second after convert Date to ZoneDateTime in JDK 11

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, java-11

Here is the Code snippet

Date is from `java.util.Date`

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = 
        ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println("ZonedDateTime before converting from Date, "
                   + "ZonedDateTime Nano is :"+ zonedDateTime.getNano());
Date zonedDateTimeToDate = 
        Date.from(zonedDateTime.toInstant());
System.out.println("Date which is converting from zonedDateTime:"
                   + zonedDateTimeToDate.toString());
ZonedDateTime afterConversionFromDateToZonedDateTime =
        ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(zonedDateTimeToDate.toInstant(),
                                ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println("ZonedDateTime after converting from Date, "
                   + " ZonedDateTime Nano is :"
                   + afterConversionFromDateToZonedDateTime.getNano());
```

Here is the result of above code

```
ZonedDateTime before converting from Date, ZonedDateTime Nano is : 221953000
Date which is converting from zonedDateTime:Tue Mar 21 16:00:31 IST 2023
ZonedDateTime after converting from Date, ZonedDateTime Nano is :221000000
```

you can clearly observe from above output the Nanosecond last 6 digit is different.

Is anyone got this kind of issue.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `java.util.Date`? It has been obsolete for 10 years or so now. Of course it doesn't have the correct resolution.

Comment: Thanks @RealSkeptic for the response, yeah I know but it's in the legacy code. I'll will discuss this with my team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html) says (emphasis mine):

> The class `Date` represents a specific instant in time, with ***millisecond*** precision.

whereas the documentation for [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) says:

> `ZonedDateTime` is an immutable representation of a date-time with a time-zone. This class stores all date and time fields, to a precision of ***nanoseconds***, and a time-zone, with a zone offset used to handle ambiguous local date-times.

Therefore, converting a `Date` to `ZonedDateTime` and then back is kind of like converting a `double` to `float` and then back - you'd sometimes not get the original value back, because information was lost when converting to `float`/`Date`.

```
double x = 1.234567891234;
System.out.println(x); // 1.234567891234
System.out.println((float)x); // 1.2345679
System.out.println((double)(float)x); // 1.2345678806304932
```

Of course, sometimes you do get the original value back, like with the `double` value `1`, which can be represented exactly with `float`. Or, in this case, with `ZonedDateTime`s that land exactly on the millisecond. Though, if your system clock has a higher resolution than milliseconds, the chance of getting that from `now` is pretty low.

Anyway, if you can, try not using `Date` at all.

Comment: Hi @Sweeper, Thanks for your answer. Sorry I didn't mentioned that this piece of code giving correct result in Java 8. Is there anything updated in Java 11?

Comment: @RahulSharma that depends on your definition of “correct”. `Date` never stores nanoseconds and that’s what your question was about. But if you use it with a clock implementation that doesn’t have nanosecond precision, the values happen to match because the nanosecond fraction will always be zero.

Comment: @RahulSharma Agreed with Holger here. `now` uses the best system clock available. In your Java 11 environment, it could very well be the case that a clock with better resolution than millisecond is available, while in your Java 8 environment such a clock is not available.

Comment: @RahulSharma You could truncate all your `ZonedDateTime`s to milliseconds before doing he conversion, `.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS)`, then you will always be able to round-trip. Alternatively, pass a millisecond-resolution clock into `now`, like `.now(Clock.tick(Clock.systemUTC(), Duration.ofMillis(1)))`. Though I feel like this is kind of like covering your eyes and saying the world doesn't exist - you are losing information *anyway*.

Comment: …or use `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).plusNanos(123456)` at the beginning of the test code to prove that the loss of precision is always there, even if the clock doesn’t have nanosecond precision.

Comment: Thank you so much @Sweeper for your valuable input.